# swap map values to a multimap

Tags: c++, containers

I store some key-values with a map, then I need to sort them by values, I am temped to use the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> map1;
    std::multimap<int, std::string> multimap2;

    map1.insert ( std::pair<std::string, int>( "one", 4) );
    map1.insert ( std::pair<std::string, int>( "two", 2) );
    map1.insert ( std::pair<std::string, int>( "three", 2) );
    map1.insert ( std::pair<std::string, int>( "four", 1) );

    for (auto it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); ){
        multimap2.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>( it->second, it->first));
        map1.erase(it++);
    }

   for (auto it = multimap2.rbegin(); it != multimap2.rend(); ++it)
   std::cout << it->first << " --- " << it->second << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

that gives me:

4 --- one
2 --- two
2 --- three
1 --- four

as I need, yet...is there a smarter and more efficient way to obtain the same result?
It will have to work with a rather large dataset...

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to dump them into a vector, and sort that:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> pair;
std::vector<pair> v;
v.reserve(map1.size());
std::copy(map1.begin(), map1.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    [](pair const & a, pair const & b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    });
```

This will probably be faster than inserting into a `multimap`, since it only needs one memory allocation.

Comment: An even better idea is to put const pointers to the pairs in the vector and sort the vector. That avoids copying them and reduces the cost of swapping them in the vector while sorting. Note: the pairs stored in a map will be of type `std::pair<const std::string, int>`

Comment: @FredericLachasse: Yes, that's something else to try, if you don't need a self-contained result. It won't necessarily be faster, since the extra indirection will have a cost; you'd need to measure both alternatives.

Comment: Thanks! What about the bit of removing the map elements while copying? In my mind that was useful to reduce the memory requirements...

Comment: @Xarylem: You'd need a loop similar to yours rather than `std::copy`. It might be slower though.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to build a bidirectional map abstraction (basically you already use this technique). This kind of class may be useful if you have arbitrary get_by_key/get_by_value queries.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class bi_map
{
private:
    std::map<K, V>      key_to_value_;
    std::multimap<V, K> value_to_key_;

public:
    typedef typename std::multimap<typename V, typename K>::iterator by_value_iterator;
    typedef typename std::map<K, V>::iterator  by_key_iterator;
    const V& value(const K& key) {
        return key_to_value_[key];
    }

    std::pair<by_value_iterator, by_value_iterator> keys(const V& value) {
        return value_to_key_.equal_range(value);
    }

    void set(const K& key, const V& value) {
        by_key_iterator it = key_to_value_.find(key);
        if (key_to_value_.end() != it) {
            std::pair<by_value_iterator, by_value_iterator> it_pair = value_to_key_.equal_range(key_to_value_[key]);
            while (it_pair.first != it_pair.second)
                if (it_pair.first->first == it->second) {
                    value_to_key_.erase(it_pair.first);
                    break;
                } else ++it_pair.first;
        }
        key_to_value_[key] = value;
        value_to_key_.insert(std::make_pair(value, key));
    }
};
```